# R: How to use "stack" instead of "stack" (from raster package)?

Tags: r

I want to use the `stack` function in base R as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837293/r-how-to-group-and-aggregate-list-elements-using-regex) of my earlier question. However, I am also using the `raster` package (which contains also a `stack` function) and this package retrieves always the error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

Is there a way to assign the package to the function? Or an idea how to use the stack function in base R and not of raster package?

Here the reproducible example of my earlier question:

```
library(raster)
group1 <- c(101, 106)
group2 <- c(102, 104)
group3 <- c(105, 103)
S <- stack(list(group1 = group1, group2 = group2, group3 = group3))
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the prefix `utils::` like this

```
S <- utils::stack(list(group1 = group1, group2 = group2, group3 = group3))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this type of coding already, but I didn't understand it before.

Comment: I don't know much about coding theory (I'm rather using these things practically). I *think* that the proper terminology is that `::` specifies the namespace from which the function is chosen, but I'll be happy to be corrected if there is a more accurate explanation.